# Android - How works MortarScope?

Tags: android, mortar

I'm currently taking in my hands an Android App to make a new version of it. The App has been made without Activities nor Fragments. You know, an App developed by someone passionated by abstraction... In there, the concept of ***MortarScope*** is used everywhere but really cannot figure out how it works and what is the purpose of that, as well as ***Mortar***. I know there is the documentation [here](https://github.com/square/mortar) but a clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I search for `square mortar android` on search engines, I find resources like https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/simpler-android-apps-with-flow-and-mortar-5beafcd83761 and https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/an-investigation-into-flow-and-mortar/ and https://academy.realm.io/posts/using-flow-mortar/. You might want to edit your question and explain **specifically** what you do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

`MortarScope` is a `Map<String, Object>` that can have a parent that it inherits from.

```
// vague behavior mock-up
public class MortarScope {
     Map<String, Object> services = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     MortarScope parent; 

     Map<String, MortarScope> children = new LinkedHashMap<>();

     public MortarScope(MortarScope parent) {
         this.parent = parent;
     }

     public boolean hasService(String tag) {
         return services.contains(tag);
     }

     @Nullable
     public <T> T getService(String tag) {
         if(services.contains(tag)) { 
             // noinspection unchecked
             return (T)services.get(tag);
         }
         if(parent == null) {
             return null;
         }
         return parent.getService(tag);
     }
}
```

The tricky thing is that a `MortarScope` can be placed into a `MortarContextWrapper`, using `mortarScope.createContext(context)`, which will allow you to obtain services from the MortarScope using `getSystemService` (apparently only on local-level).

This works because `ContextWrapper`s create a hierarchy, and `getSystemService()` also does a hierarchical look-up.

```
class MortarContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
  private final MortarScope scope;

  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public MortarContextWrapper(Context context, MortarScope scope) {
    super(context);
    this.scope = scope;
  }

  @Override public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    if (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
      if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).cloneInContext(this);
      }
      return inflater;
    }
    return scope.hasService(name) ? scope.getService(name) : super.getSystemService(name);
  }
}
```

This can make a View's context wrapper store a `MortarScope` if it is created like this

```
LayoutInflater.from(mortarScope.createContext(this)).inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false);
```

This means that when you do something like this:

```
public class MyService {
    public static MyService get(Context context) {
         // noinspection ResourceType
         return (MyService)context.getSystemService("MY_SERVICE");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyView extends View {
    ...
    MyService myService = MyService.get(getContext());
```

Then you can force the `getSystemService()` to obtain `MyService` from any level above you through a hierarchical look-up across the contexts (view, activity, application).

---

The parent retains the child unless explicitly destroyed, so the `Activity` scope is kept alive by the `Application` scope, and the `View` scope is kept alive by the `Activity` scope, therefore configuration change does not destroy services stored inside a MortarScope.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So If I understand well, the main purpose of Mortar and MortarScope is to encapsulate services inside the context and allow to use them through getSystemService ?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  and additionally the parent keeps the mortar scopes alive unless explicitly destroyed, so all services in the mortar scope survive configuration change (f.ex. Rotations)